# is it correct to say "crying from"?

Tags: word-usage

is it ok to say 'crying from' meaning 'because of'? Like in

> I was crying from (because of) a thought about my future.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to say "because of"?

Comment: only not to repeat it too often (writing a story)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't incorrect, it just doesn't quite fit your context.

When highlighting the *cause* of someone's tears, we normally say someone is crying *at* something, *due to* something, or *because of* something.

However, examples such as "crying from stress" and "crying from emotion" are easily found if you Google, and in the context are perfectly idiomatic. We also commonly say "crying *with* laughter".

Comment: thank you very much! :)

Comment: "Crying from the thought of my future" seems right, but also seems to carry a separate meaning from the two.